# Why "main" symbol doesn't stripped in pie binary?

Tags: assembly, binary, strip, position-independent-code

Like any other symbols, `main` is classified as static symbol,
So this usually disappears when binary is stripped.
However, yesterday I found this `main` function doesn't stripped in `pie` binaries.

I defined several symbols in my sample C program, `myfunc1`, `myfunc2`, ... , and `main`.
And I found any other symbols does disappear when I strip the binary, but  `main` symbol still alived after stripped.

I inspected the reasons, and found `main` was classified as *dynamic symbol* unlike any other user-defined symbols.

```
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 13 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
    // ...omitted...
    10: 000005e0    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    11: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
    12: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
```

***Question:***
Why `main` is classified as dynamic symbol in `pie` binary?
(I think it would be okay `main` strip, like it is in the `non-pie binary`.)

Comment: I think it's because `__libc_start_main` in glibc calls `main`.  Although possibly the statically linked CRT start code passes the address of `main` to its parent, so I'm not sure.